How to store the matching values to single object in powershell
I'm having an output with object alltags and need an sorted output for another script to pick up the values
ip-id 19900909.1
ip-license 19900906.2
ip-finalsync 19900906.2
ip-tubelas 19900909.1
ip-id 19900809.1
ip-license 19900905.2
ip-finalsync 19900606.2
ip-tubelas 19900709.1
ip-id 19900509.1
ip-license 19900406.2
ip-finalsync 19900306.2
ip-tubelas 19900309.1

Expecting an output with
ip-id = "19900909.1","19900809.1", "19900509.1"
ip-license = "19900906.2", "19900905.2", "19900406.2"
ip-finalsync = "19900306.2", "19900906.2", "19900606.2"
ip-tubelas =  ".,.,."

$alltags.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType

True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

how is the variable being populated? If we don't know its structure it's pretty difficult to help.

Write-Output $alltags

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


Use a hashtable or other dictionary type to store one entry per prefix/label:
$allTags = @'
ip-id 19900909.1
ip-license 19900906.2
ip-finalsync 19900906.2
ip-tubelas 19900909.1
ip-id 19900809.1
ip-license 19900905.2
ip-finalsync 19900606.2
ip-tubelas 19900709.1
ip-id 19900509.1
ip-license 19900406.2
ip-finalsync 19900306.2
ip-tubelas 19900309.1
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# create ordered dictionary
$tagSets = [ordered]@{}

# populate dictionary
$allTags |ForEach-Object {
  $label,$value = $_ -split '\s+',2

  # create entry for label if it doesn't already exist
  if (-not $tagSets.Contains($label)) {
    $tagSets.Add($label, @())
  }

  # add value to entry
  $tagSets[$label] += $value
}

Now you can easily get all the values associated with ip-license for example:
PS ~> $tagSets['ip-license']
19900906.2
19900905.2
19900406.2


You can also produce the desired output regardless of whether you know the labels up front or not:
$tagSets.GetEnumerator() |ForEach-Object {
  $formattedValueList = $(@($_.Value).ForEach({"""$_"""}) -join ', ')
  '{0} = {1}' -f $_.Key,$formattedValueList
}


I'm having dynamic values in a variable
passing values into $alltags is not possible is there any other way
Write-Output $alltags is giving values as below
ip-id 19900909.1
ip-license 19900906.2
ip-finalsync 19900906.2
ip-tubelas 19900909.1
ip-id 19900809.1
ip-license 19900905.2
ip-finalsync 19900606.2
ip-tubelas 19900709.1
ip-id 19900509.1
ip-license 19900406.2
ip-finalsync 19900306.2
ip-tubelas 19900309.1

@Saikumar You don't need to know the labels ahead of time in order to produce the output you describe, I've updated the answer :)
